# jquery array to string to display textbox input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

im trying to output the arrays associated with the `test` variable:

```
            $(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function(){
                var test = $("input[name*='i_name']");                   
                $(test).each(function(i, item){
                    var sample = [];
                    sample.push($(item).val());

                });                 
            });
```

and display all the data i got into a textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test[]">
```

how will i do it it? i tried `JSON.stringify`, `.join` but it only displays the last index of the array. please assist me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting your sample array in every iteration, remove the variable declaration from the loop.

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function() {
    var test = $("input[name*='i_name']");
    var sample = [];    // <-- Define sample variable here
    $(test).each(function(i, item){
        sample.push($(item).val());
    });

    console.log(sample.join(", "));
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :) If this solved your question, consider marking this as the solution so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `sample` array in  global variable of click function, not with `each` function .Because each time loop will be reset the array.That why its have only last element value

```
 $(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function(){
          var sample = [];
                var test = $("input[name*='i_name']");                   
                $(test).each(function(i, item){
                    sample.push($(item).val());

                });                 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function(){
                var sample = [];
                var test = $("input[name*='i_name']");                   
                test.each(function(i, item){

                    sample.push($(item).val());

                });                 
            });
```

> I think.. I should change $(test) => test

Comment: Please correct your answer by putting `;` after `var sample = []`

Answer (score 0):

You can output the array to the `input` box by just updating the value.

In your code, your `sample` variable is getting updated to empty array `[]` each time, hence it is storing only the latest value.

```js
const text = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

$("#test").val(text.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main mistakes, you are clearing the array each time inside the loop, declare var sample = [], globally, 
seconding using the wrong selector, directly use the jquery object than assigning to a variable and using it.

```
 $(document).on('click','#btnSubmit', function(){
                      var sample = [];             
                $("input[name*='i_name']").each(function(i, item){
                    sample.push($(item).val());
                });
                console.log(sample.toString()); // it will convert to string.
            });
```

Hope it helps.